# Hash table implemented in C with open addressing

Tags: c, hash-map, collections

While posting this, I noticed there are *quite* a few similar C hash table implementations here already. So I figured one more wouldn't hurt. :-) In any case, I'm writing a teaching article on "how to implement a hash table in C", and I'm wondering if I can get some feedback on my implementation (`ht.h` and `ht.c`, with a usage example in `demo.c`). The goal is *not* maximum performance, but simplicity and good style.

This hash table is a very simple array of entries that uses open addressing and linear probing, and the FNV-1 hash function. The capacity is always a power of two, and it automatically expands and re-hashes when it's half full.

A few notes about the C API design:

- For simplicity, we use C-style NUL-terminated strings. I know there are more efficient approaches to string handling, but this fits with C's standard library.
- The `ht_set` function allocates and copies the key (if inserting for the first time). Usually you don't want the caller to have to worry about this, or ensuring the key memory stays around. Note that `ht_set` returns a pointer to the duplicated key. This is mainly used as an "out of memory" error signal -- it returns NULL on failure.
- Values can't be NULL. This makes the return value of `ht_get` slightly simpler (NULL means not present and can't mean a NULL value). I'm not sure whether this is a good idea or not.
- There are various ways I could have done iteration. Using an explicit iterator type with a while loop seems simple and natural in C (see the example below). The value returned from `ht_iterator` is a value, not a pointer, both for efficiency and so the caller doesn't have to free anything.
- There's no `ht_remove` to remove an item from the hash table. It wouldn't be hard to write, but I don't often need to remove items when using a hash table, so for simplicity I've left it out.

**ht.h:**

```c
#ifndef _HT_H
#define _HT_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>

// Hash table entry (this is not actually part of the public API).
typedef struct {
    char* key;
    void* value;
} _ht_entry;

// Hash table structure: create with ht_create, free with ht_destroy.
typedef struct {
    // Don't use these fields directly.
    _ht_entry* _entries; // hash buckets (entry.key != NULL if populated)
    size_t _capacity;    // size of _entries array
    size_t _length;      // number of items in hash table
} ht;

// Hash table iterator: create with ht_iterator, iterate with ht_next.
typedef struct {
    char* key;      // current key
    void* value;    // current value

    // Don't use these fields directly.
    ht* _table;     // reference to hash table being iterated
    size_t _index;  // current index into ht._entries
} hti;

// Create new hash table and return pointer to it, or NULL if out of
// memory.
ht* ht_create(void);

// Free memory allocated for hash table, including allocated keys.
void ht_destroy(ht* table);

// Get item with given key (NUL-terminated) from hash table. Return
// value (which was set with ht_set), or NULL if key not found.
void* ht_get(ht* table, const char* key);

// Set item with given key (NUL-terminated) to value (which must not
// be NULL). If not already present in table, key is copied to newly
// allocated memory (keys are freed automatically when ht_destroy is
// called). Return address of copied key, or NULL if out of memory.
const char* ht_set(ht* table, const char* key, void* value);

// Return number of items in hash table.
size_t ht_length(ht* table);

// Return new hash table iterator (for use with ht_next).
hti ht_iterator(ht* table);

// Move iterator to next item in hash table, update iterator's key
// and value to current item, and return true. If there are no more
// items, return false. Don't call ht_set during iteration.
bool ht_next(hti* it);

#endif // _HT_H
```

**ht.c:**

```c
#include "ht.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INITIAL_SIZE 8

static ht* _ht_create(size_t size) {
    // Allocate space for hash table struct.
    ht* table = malloc(sizeof(ht));
    if (table == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    table->_length = 0;
    table->_capacity = size * 2;

    // Allocate (zero'd) space for entry buckets.
    table->_entries = calloc(table->_capacity, sizeof(_ht_entry));
    if (table->_entries == NULL) {
        free(table); // error, free table before we return!
        return NULL;
    }
    return table;
}

ht* ht_create(void) {
    return _ht_create(INITIAL_SIZE);
}

void ht_destroy(ht* table) {
    // First free allocated keys.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < table->_capacity; i++) {
        if (table->_entries[i].key != NULL) {
            free(table->_entries[i].key);
        }
    }

    // Then free entries array and table itself.
    free(table->_entries);
    free(table);
}

#define FNV_OFFSET 14695981039346656037UL
#define FNV_PRIME 1099511628211UL

// Return 64-bit FNV-1 hash for key (NUL-terminated). See description at:
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler–Noll–Vo_hash_function
static uint64_t _hash(const char* key) {
    uint64_t hash = FNV_OFFSET;
    for (const char* p = key; *p; p++) {
        hash *= FNV_PRIME;
        hash ^= (uint64_t)(*p);
    }
    return hash;
}

void* ht_get(ht* table, const char* key) {
    // AND hash with capacity-1 to ensure it's within entries array.
    uint64_t hash = _hash(key);
    size_t index = (size_t)(hash & (uint64_t)(table->_capacity - 1));

    // Loop till we find an empty entry.
    while (table->_entries[index].key != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(key, table->_entries[index].key) == 0) {
            // Found key, return value.
            return table->_entries[index].value;
        }
        // Key wasn't in this slot, move to next (linear probing).
        index++;
        if (index >= table->_capacity) {
            // At end of entries array, wrap around.
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

// Expand hash table to twice its current size. Return true on success,
// false if out of memory.
static bool _ht_expand(ht* table) {
    // Creating new table so we can use ht_set to move items into it.
    ht* new_table = _ht_create(table->_capacity);
    if (new_table == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    // Iterate entries, move all non-empty ones to new table's entries.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < table->_capacity; i++) {
        _ht_entry entry = table->_entries[i];
        if (entry.key != NULL) {
            const char* key = ht_set(new_table, entry.key, entry.value);
            if (key == NULL) {
                ht_destroy(new_table);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Free old entries array and update this table's details.
    free(table->_entries);
    table->_entries = new_table->_entries;
    table->_capacity = new_table->_capacity;

    // Free new table structure (we've updated the existing one).
    free(new_table);
    return true;
}

const char* ht_set(ht* table, const char* key, void* value) {
    assert(value != NULL);
    if (value == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // AND hash with capacity-1 to ensure it's within entries array.
    uint64_t hash = _hash(key);
    size_t index = (size_t)(hash & (uint64_t)(table->_capacity - 1));

    // If length will exceed half of current capacity, expand it.
    if (table->_length >= table->_capacity / 2) {
        if (!_ht_expand(table)) {
            return NULL;
        }
        // Recalculate index as capacity has changed.
        index = (size_t)(hash & (uint64_t)(table->_capacity - 1));
    }

    // Loop till we find an empty entry.
    while (table->_entries[index].key != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(key, table->_entries[index].key) == 0) {
            // Found key (it already exists), update value.
            table->_entries[index].value = value;
            return table->_entries[index].key;
        }
        // Key wasn't in this slot, move to next (linear probing).
        index++;
        if (index >= table->_capacity) {
            // At end of entries array, wrap around.
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Didn't find key, allocate/copy key and insert it.
    char* key_copy = strdup(key);
    if (key_copy == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    table->_entries[index].key = key_copy;
    table->_entries[index].value = value;
    table->_length++; // be sure to update length
    return key_copy;
}

size_t ht_length(ht* table) {
    return table->_length;
}

hti ht_iterator(ht* table) {
    hti it;
    it._table = table;
    it._index = 0;
    return it;
}

bool ht_next(hti* it) {
    // Loop till we've hit end of entries array.
    ht* table = it->_table;
    while (it->_index < table->_capacity) {
        size_t i = it->_index;
        it->_index++;
        if (table->_entries[i].key != NULL) {
            // Found next non-empty item, update iterator key and value.
            _ht_entry entry = table->_entries[i];
            it->key = entry.key;
            it->value = entry.value;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And now for a simple example of usage:

**demo.c:**

```c
#include "../ht.h"

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Example:
// $ echo 'foo bar the bar bar bar the' | ./demo
// bar 4
// foo 1
// the 2
// 3

void exit_nomem(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
}

int main(void) {
    ht* counts = ht_create();
    if (counts == NULL) {
        exit_nomem();
    }

    // Read next word from stdin (at most 100 chars long).
    char word[101];
    while (scanf("%100s", word) != EOF) {
        // Look up word.
        void* value = ht_get(counts, word);
        if (value != NULL) {
            // Already exists, increment int that value points to.
            int* pcount = (int*)value;
            (*pcount)++;
            continue;
        }

        // Word not found, allocate space for new int and set to 1.
        int* pcount = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (pcount == NULL) {
            exit_nomem();
        }
        *pcount = 1;
        if (ht_set(counts, word, pcount) == NULL) {
            exit_nomem();
        }
    }

    // Print out words and frequencies, freeing values as we go.
    hti it = ht_iterator(counts);
    while (ht_next(&it)) {
        printf("%s %d\n", it.key, *(int*)it.value);
        free(it.value);
    }

    // Show the number of unique words.
    printf("%d\n", (int)ht_length(counts));

    ht_destroy(counts);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you would use FNV1 and not use FNV1a?

Comment: I've actually switched to 1a! After testing average probe length, I noticed 1 wasn't good with similar keys like "word1", "word2", etc, whereas 1a did fine with those (and normal words). Not very scientific, but yeah, 1a, seems better. https://github.com/benhoyt/ht/commit/bf83fb7fd27e636a09822a31cf8617f311121c3d

Comment: Article published: https://benhoyt.com/writings/hash-table-in-c/ I included a bunch of changes based on this feedback, notably: fixing the memory leak, moving (most) struct internals to `ht.c`, dropping the `_` prefix on internal names, and fixing the sign extension issue in `_hash`. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `// Don't use these fields directly` means that they do not belong to the public interface. Consider declaring

  ```
    typedef struct ht ht;
  ```

  in `ht.h`, and spelling it out in `ht.c`. Ditto for `hti`.

  `_ht_entry` shall not be visible to the client at all; move its declaration to `ht.c` as well.
- `ht_set` calls `_ht_expand`. In turn, `_ht_expand` calls `ht_set`. Even though it is (apparently) safe, it still looks eery.

  What worse, `ht_set` does `strdup(key)`, but `_ht_expand` does not free the old keys. Memory leak it is.
- The values must be persistent, and I don't see the way for the client to not `malloc` them (the demo code seems to agree with me). However `ht_destroy` does not free them. This is yet another avenue for a memory leak.
- I am not sure you should force FNV. The user - who knows the nature of the keys distribution - may want to use different hashing algorithm. Besides, FNV is well-scattered across the entire 64-bit space. I have serious doubts that it will perform well after clipping to the narrower space.

Comment: Thanks! Good points about moving non-public things to ht.c. Good find on the `_ht_expand` memory leak! I'm not sure about `ht_destroy` freeing values -- the user might malloc a block of values and point into that, so needs control. Re FNV and clipping - interesting point. Looks like http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/ has useful info.

Comment: FNV seems to have pretty good "dispersion" (as it's called) for hashes that are powers of two. However, I just noticed FNV-1a works much better than FNV-1 for similar keys like `key1`, `key2`, etc. So I think I'll switch to 1a.

Answer (score 6):

**Good header file**

.... aside from the `struct` definitions that belong in the .c file.

**Weak hash**

OP's code only uses the least few bits of `hash` to form `index` and so this `ht` exercise entirely relies on the quality of `_hash()`.

```
// Only uses a few bits of `hash`
size_t index = (size_t)(hash & (uint64_t)(table->_capacity - 1));
```

Consider a [mod by prime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32915815/2410359) for general hash functions.  I'd use a look-up table of primes just under a power-of-4 and grow the hash table approximately 4x when needed.

**Size to the referenced object, not the type.**

Consider the below. Is `sizeof(_ht_entry)` correct?  To check, I needed to search for the type of `table` (somewhere at the start of the function) , find `ht`, search for `ht` definition (it is in another file).

```
// size by type: easy to code worng, slow to review, more maintenance on change.
table->_entries = calloc(table->_capacity, sizeof(_ht_entry));
```

Instead, consider

```
table->_entries = calloc(table->_capacity, sizeof table->_entries[0]);
// or
table->_entries = calloc(table->_capacity, sizeof *(table->_entries));
```

Easy to code right, review and maintain.  No need to look up `table`, nor `_entries` definition.

**Keep empty tables small**

A *successful* container can get used *a lot*. The more it is used, more likely *many* instances remain empty thought out their life.

The initial `_ht_create(INITIAL_SIZE)` waste memory in those cases.  Consider `_ht_create(0)` instead and adjust code accordingly.  That first allocation before need does not buy much.

**Corner case bug**

(OP does not use `_ht_create(0)` yet, but ...)

Below tests for out-of-memory by `table->_entries == NULL`, yet a `NULL` is an acceptable return value when `table->_capacity == 0`.  (C17 somewhat addresses this, but not enough).

```
table->_entries = calloc(table->_capacity, sizeof(_ht_entry));
// if (table->_entries == NULL) {
// Suggest
if (table->_entries == NULL && table->_capacity > 0) {
```

**Drop the _ prefix**

No need for it.

**How to set/get `NULL` data**

I disagree with restricting use with "Values can't be NULL".

With "NULL if key not found", implies ambiguity if the value stored prior was `NULL`.

Rather than mix the result of the `get()` with a reserved pointer value, separate the error flag from data.  The data value should be allowed to be *any* `void *`.

**`const`**

Function deserves to be `const` for the usual reasons of self-documentation and expanded use.

```
// size_t ht_length(ht* table);
size_t ht_length(const ht* table);
```

**Initialize all of the iterator**

```
hti ht_iterator(ht* table) {
    //hti it;
    //it._table = table;
    //it._index = 0;
    hti it = { ._table = table, ._index = 0 }; // other members become 0
    return it;
}
```

**Shrink**

I look forward to `ht_remove()`.

No support to remove entries or shrink the table other than to destroy.

**Minor: `L` not needed**

```
//#define FNV_OFFSET 14695981039346656037UL
//#define FNV_PRIME 1099511628211UL
#define FNV_OFFSET 14695981039346656037U
#define FNV_PRIME 1099511628211U
```

**Minor: Avoid sign extension**

```
// hash ^= (uint64_t)(*p);
hash ^= *(unsigned char *)p;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll make some of these updates. Good call on the hashing sign extension bug -- I actually noticed that myself just before reading your reply. It gives an incorrect hash as a result (though it didn't seem to matter to much in practice). I've updated my code.